# how can you improve this algorithm for finding the smallest positive integer not in an array

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```
function findSmallestPositiveInteger(A) {


    // sort array from smallest to largest number
     A.sort((a, b) => a - b)
     
    // remove duplicates because they just would take memory
    const noDups =Array.from(new Set(A).keys())
    
    let smallestPositiveInteger=1
    
    let previous = noDups[0]
    if(previous <= smallestPositiveInteger && previous>0)
            smallestPositiveInteger++
    
    for(let i =1;i<noDups.length;i++){
      const v = noDups[i]
      if(previous > 0){
         const diffWithPrevious = v - previous
         // the logic for this early return is that we might not need to traverse
         // the whole array for example imagine this example 
         // [1,2,5,6,8,...n]
         // its clear that there is a gap between 5 and 2 so we can just 
         // conclude that 2+1 is the smallest postive integer not in our array 
         if(diffWithPrevious > 1) return previous +1;      
      }
      
      // check if smallest positive integer in array is not 1
      // if so return 1 
      if(previous == 0 && v > 1 ) return 1
      
      if(v <= smallestPositiveInteger && v>0)
         smallestPositiveInteger++
       previous = v
    }

    return smallestPositiveInteger
}


const arr =[-1,-2,1,3,10,9,3,2,3,3,10,2,7,99,100,10000,500,50,60,70,33]

console.log(findSmallestPositiveInteger(arr))
```

Comment: Use a loop, skip numbers less than 1, any other number see if its less than a stored value.  Using sort would be inefficent here.

Comment: @Keith - How do you imagine this to work. Initially, I thought the suggestion sounded good. But without sorting the array and using a single loop, how can one be sure that a given number is found/not-found? How would you manage the following input for instance? [100,2,-20,4,6,,4,1,3]

Comment: @enhzflep exactly I was just giving it a try now it seems like a sort is inevitable .

Comment: You get an array of integers and you can NOT use an array inside the solution? can you clarify the question?

Comment: @gilamran hmm I'm sure I understand your question , basically what this is saying lets say we gave you an array of integers your task is to find the smallest positive integer that is not in that array for example if input is  [1,2,6,7,-1,-6] output should be 3.

Comment: hooo, better clarify that in the question...

Comment: @gilamran you're right although I asked the question in a manner that requires you to already know about the algorithm .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the integers from the array into a lookup structure, and then just try natural numbers starting from `1` until you find one that was not in the array:

```
function findSmallestPositiveInteger(arr) {
    const lookup = new Set(arr);
    let i = 1;
    while (lookup.has(i)) {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Would this be more efficient, if you were to take, lets say 3 random samples from the array, take a median of those and go down from there? This one might take a while if the smallest number not in the array is very large.

Comment: @Swiffy It won't take longer than `new Set(arr)` which has to go through the whole array anyway. And how would taking the median produce the correct result? You still have to confirm that all values smaller than it exist in the array.

Comment: @Bergi I'm talking about starting from `i = median_of_random_sample_off_arr` and doing `i--` in the loop, as I was just figuring off the top of my head that if the smallest nonexisting number is very large and `i` starts from 0, that would be the worst case scenario for this implementation. Actually now that I think of it, the median is a stupid idea, you could just take minimum instead, but either way the random sample would have more relation to the set of numbers than just starting blindy from 1.

Comment: @Bergi Actually never mind :D I wasn't thinking straight.

Answer (score 2):

I guess I'd go about it in the following manner.

0. sort the array, treating each element as a number (arr.sort treats as a strnig without a compare function)
1. set a target variable to 1
2. stepping through the elements, if my target is found, increment the number we now look for
3. when finished looping, return the value that we were last searching for

A little something like this I supppose.

```js
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onLoad, false);
function onLoad(evt)
{
    let arr =[-1,-2,1,3,10,9,3,2,3,3,10,2,7,99,100,10000,500,50,60,70,33];
    test(arr);
}

function test(arr)
{
    arr = arr.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
    let nextTgt = 1;
    arr.forEach( el => { if (el==nextTgt) nextTgt++ ;} );
    console.log(arr);
    console.log(nextTgt);
}
```

**EDIT**: A vast improvement would break from the loop if the current array element being examined is larger than the current search target.

```
function test2(arr)
{
    arr = arr.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
    let nextTgt = 1;
    for (var i=0,n=arr.length; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == nextTgt)
            nextTgt++;
        else if (arr[i]>nextTgt)
            break;
    }
    console.log(arr);
    console.log(nextTgt);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution which does not sort, runs in O(n) (it scans the entire array exactly twice) and doesn't require any additional temporary array. But it does rearrange the original array.

The `isInteger` eliminates the possibility of treating a string as an integer, as JavaScript likes to do, which is why the sample returns 5; the function doesn't consider the string `'5'` to be an integer. I think that's correct, but YMMV.

```js
const myArray = [-1,-2,1,3,"5",10,9,3,2,3,4,10,2,7,99,100,10000,500,50,60,70,33, Infinity]

function findSmallestPositive(arr) {
  for (let idx=0; idx<arr.length; idx++) {
    const val = arr[idx];
    if (Number.isInteger(val) && 0 <= val && val < arr.length) {
      arr[idx] = arr[val-1];
      arr[val-1] = val;
    }
  }
  // At this point, the values are rearranged so that arr[i-1] is i
  // if and only if i is in the array. Now scan again to find the
  // smallest missing value.
  for (let idx=1; idx<=arr.length; idx++) {
    if (!(Number.isInteger(arr[idx-1]) && arr[idx-1] == idx)) {
      return idx;
    }
  }
  return arr.length + 1;
}

console.time()
console.log(findSmallestPositive(myArray))
console.timeEnd()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the sorting and build out an object where the keys are the values in the array. Then just iterate over the arrays length and break at the first missing number.

```js
function findSmallestPositiveInteger(A) {
    const noDups = Object.assign({} , ...A.map((x) => ({[x]: true})));
    let smallestPositiveInteger = 1
    for (let i = 1; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (typeof noDups[i] == 'undefined') {
            smallestPositiveInteger = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return smallestPositiveInteger;
}


const arr = [-1, -2, 1, 3, 10, 9, 3, 2, 3, 3, 10, 2, 7, 99, 100, 10000, 500, 50, 60, 70, 33]

console.log(findSmallestPositiveInteger(arr))
```

Comment: interesting I forgot about this approach , I used it to create a very performant "remove duplicates from array algorithm " duplicates algorithm .

Comment: if the array is `[-1, 1, 9007199254740991]`? it will take forever!

Comment: @gilamran, not necessarily. It'll break at 2

Comment: ok so `[9007199254740990, 9007199254740991]`

Comment: it'll break at 1

Comment: @gilamran that's the beauty of it you don't need to traverse the while array

Comment: Hoo I see, right

Comment: You should not even need `highestValue` - just `A.length` should be fine if you want *some* bound on the loop. (`Math.max(...A)` is only useful if there's a lot of duplicates in the array, but even then you'd find that after iterating `noDups` until the number of distinct values)

Comment: @Bergi very good point, I've updated with your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

First of all, filtering is O(n), therefore anything like negative numbers or non-integers are irrelevant. After that, the highest number it can be is at most the array's length plus one (and you are guaranteed to find one from one to that number).

You can track every one of these in O(n):

```js
const helper = arr => {
  const marks = Array(arr.length + 1).fill(false);
  for (const n of arr) {
    if (n < marks.length) marks[n - 1] = true;
  }
  return marks.findIndex(e => !e) + 1;
};

const findSmallestPositiveInteger = arr => helper(arr.filter(e => Number.isInteger(e) && e > 0));

const arr = [-1, -2, 1, 3, 10, 9, 3, 2, 3, 3, 10, 2, 7, 99, 100, 10000, 500, 50, 60, 70, 33]

console.log(findSmallestPositiveInteger(arr))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const smallestPositiveInt = (arr) => {
   // sort and remove negatives, duplicates, float
   const sort = Array.from(new Set(arr))
     .filter(n => n >= 1 && Number.isInteger(n))
     .sort((a,b) => a - b);
  
   let smallestInt = 1;
   // if and while int isn't in array, add until you get to int that doesn't exist in array
   while(sort.includes(smallestInt)) { 
    smallestInt++; 
   }
   return smallestInt
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Experimental Approach

This method trades space complexity for time, but should be extremely **fast**. The reason we can do this in Javascript is because arrays **can be abused like hashes**

```js
const myArray = [-1,-2,1,3,10,9,3,2,3,3,10,2,7,99,100,10000,500,50,60,70,33, Infinity]

function findSmallestPositive(arr) {
  // create a new array which uses the index
  const indexed = Array(arr.length)
  // add elements as the index of the new array
  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > 0) indexed[arr[i]] = 1
  }
  // return the first element above 0 that is missing
  for (let i=1; i<indexed.length; i++) {
    if (!indexed[i]) return i
  }
  // return undefined if nothing found
  return undefined
}

console.time()
console.log(findSmallestPositive(myArray))
console.timeEnd()
```

The idea here being we can treat arrays as sorted hash maps, then we just need to find the first index which is `undefined`.

**NOTE**: arrays can be implemented under the hood in a variety of ways depending on the contents, platform and engine. Here is a decent deep dive into how the `V8` engine handles arrays internally:

[https://ryanpeden.com/how-do-javascript-arrays-work-under-the-hood/#:~:text=In%20V8%2C%20if%20your%20array,by%20an%20array%20of%20doubles](https://ryanpeden.com/how-do-javascript-arrays-work-under-the-hood/#:%7E:text=In%20V8%2C%20if%20your%20array,by%20an%20array%20of%20doubles).

> you now have a sparse array. If is not too spare, it’ll still be backed by an array, with empty array indices replaced with a ‘hole’ value. If you look at V8’s C++ array source (linked below), you’ll see calls to element->is_the_hole(i). If an array is very sparse, it’ll no longer be backed by an array in memory. Instead, it will be backed by a dictionary/hashtable, and it’ll take longer to both access elements and iterate through the array.

Comment: "*arrays are hashes*" - no, not really. Yes, you can [abuse them with arbitrary keys](https://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/), but you shouldn't. Use an object, `Map` or `Set` for that purpose. Modern engines implement arrays with array-backed storage, and fall back to lookup-based collections only for very sparse arrays.

Comment: I like your approach (same as the one i posted), but your part about arrays being hashtables is very inaccurate, and taking ancient answers (from 2009) somewhat out of context.

Comment: Yeah I know this isn't the right way to do it haha, but there's plenty of other answers on here so maybe this is for a leet code where time might matter. Just added some caveats above

Comment: You seem to be under the impression, that hash tables are faster than arrays. They are not. If you know the index of an array, all you need to do is jump to that offset in memory. Tl;dr; your approach isn't the problem, it's your remarks about hashtables, which in most cases aren't true.

Comment: @ASDFGerte yeah what I meant to say was we can use them in a similar fashion, just updated the answer to reflect this part thanks!